# 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of a navigation property;

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list, sharepointdocumentlibrary

How can I save document library lookup field using REST API Post in a SharePoint list?
I tried like

```
'docItem':'1;#test'
```

But, it is throwing an error :

> ```json
> {
>   "error": {
>     "code": "-1,Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
>     "message": {
>       "lang": "en-US",
>       "value": "A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non - null value was found when trying to read the value of a navigation property;however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected."
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Bad Request

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming the lookup field name is docItem simply using

```
'docItemId':1
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check any of list column name match with any predefined column name in share point,if so  change that column name.For me I have a Author column (people and group datatype we have /Author navigation) in list that  troubled me so I  changed that name to AuthorName and its started working then.

Answer (score -2):

Yes please save it like below:

where Model is ng-model.

ctrlSub is controller.

```
data = {'FieldId' :ctrlSub.Model.Id.toString()}
```

Comment: In mentioning Controllers and Models, this would be for a C# .NET MVC instance.  You also wouldn't want to send the ID to string, but let it stay as `int`.  The OP was asking about the REST API, which, from the error, is using JavaScript.